# I'm under attack. I ask help

Tags: support, down-votes

It's purely management question to the moderators team. In topic ["Can we set up svn server on a local computer without any network access?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access) (and probably some other places) I'm under [downvoting attack](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268265_142131) from person, known as [Mark Booth](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/22493/mark-booth). He decrease rating of my correct answer in retaliation for criticism ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268263_142128) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268271_142128)) of his response, which contains offtopic partially and for my -1 on other offtopic answers in this topic

**I ask for support and protection** from dishonest personalized attacks on the results of my labor.

I'm sorry to distract you with my problems and taking up your time - I can't see another way.

Comment: There is a built-in feature that will reverse serial downvotes and the rep lost by them, however I think it may take a few hours to kick in. I've been the target of this kind of thing in the past, and you just have to ignore it. Downvotes are meant to be part of how the site works.

Comment: As a side note, users can only downvote an answer once, and they can only downvote if they have over 125 rep, so at least 4 different users with over 125 rep downvoted one question, while 2 different users downvoted another. That doesn't look like serial downvoting by a single user to me, but rather users downvoting what they view as a low-quality or inaccurate answer

Comment: @Rachel - my "answer in question" have -2 only, I can't really see there my answer is "low-quality" (I *assume* smart OP in my answers)

Comment: Even if the OP does somehow understand what you're saying in your answer, many other users do not. We'd ideally like our questions and answers to be re-usable and to help more than just the OP, so prefer a more expanded answer than what you provided. Usually if one of my answers get downvoted, I just try and learn from the other higher-voted answers for next time and may even delete my own answer if I feel it is a bad answer or that another answer is better.

Comment: @Rachel - I don't ask "How to improve my quality" here, I'm under impression, that I'm under gang's attack for my criticism of "not an answer" answers. Downvotes in topic and other my (even old) responses are 1) remarkably *synchronous* 2) have *same amount* of 3 voices (with rare exclusions)

Answer (score 13):

Let's see if we can get something of a timeline here:

1. 15:40:40 - The [question is asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142123/25936).
2. 16:34:23 - Mark posts [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142128/25936).
3. 16:58:39 - You post [your answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142131/25936).

From here on I'll split the timeline to the two answers, starting with Mark's:

1. 18:27:19 - ["-1 for answer on non-asked by OP question. Do not consider yourself smarter than others"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268263_142128) - Comment by you on Mark's answer.
2. 18:38:42 - ["When I said about non-answered, I had in mind Mercurial recommendation only. Because rest is just my stolen and expanded correct answer"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268271_142128)
3. 18:44:13 - Mark responds to your comment with ["Unlike others here, I provided a solution with svn and then suggested an alternative."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268275_142128).
4. 18:48:59 - Mark [expands his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/142128/5) a little bit.
5. 18:50:33 - Mark informs you of his edit with this comment: ["@LazyBadger - Happy now? I actually answer the specific question asked, along with the other suggestions for alternative solutions."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268282_142128)
6. 18:53:30 - Another user steps in, [informing you that Mark's answer is actually earlier than yours](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268285_142128).
7. 19:00:29 - You post this meta question.
8. 19:06:22 - I check to see what the heck is going on, and [inform you that you can see the actual timelines by hovering over "x hours ago"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268292_142128).
9. 19:14:33 - You apologize to Mark for accusing him of stealing your answer with this comment: ["@MarkBooth - I'm sorry, you did not steal my answer. It is incomprehensible for me confusion in the update-interface of the page"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268297_142128)

And now let's see what has been happening on your answer:

1. 18:02:34 - Mark, oblivious of what would follow, [graciously fixes grammar mistakes in your answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/142131/2).
2. 18:29:35 - ["-1 for answer on non-asked by OP question. Do not consider yourself smarter than others."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268265_142131) - Mark posts this comment, obviously referencing [your comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268263_142128) in his answer, a couple of minutes earlier.

Lastly, while all these where taking place someone flagged *every* comment that was addressed to you as "rude/offensive". Then you flagged two answers on the same question for moderation attention, which I declined as "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" - that's what down votes are for.

---

Now that we reconstructed the timeline, I feel extremely confident that Mark did not do anything wrong here. He *improved* your answer, even though it was a competing *later* answer that re-iterated his own answer, and even expanded his own answer after you falsely accused him of stealing it from you.

You, on the other hand, really need to **calm down**. You accused another user of stealing you answer, although you never adequately checked to see if your answer was actually earlier, posted some rather snarky comments, flagged *perfectly valid* competing answers and I'm pretty sure that you were the one flagging almost every comment that was addressed to you, although people where generally being nice and *none* of the flagged comments was either rude or offensive.

The culmination of course is this Meta question, where you ask us to intervene for a single down vote. I'll recognize that you apologized to Mark after you found out you were in the wrong, however your overall behavior is unacceptable.

You need [to be nice(r)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette):

> #### Etiquette
>
> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.
>
> **Be nice.**
>
> Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.
>
> **Be honest.**
>
> Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!

I appreciate your passion, however the hostility you displayed today was both unwarranted and nonsensical, and our community has a very low tolerance threshold for such behaviours.

**Calm down and be nice**.

Comment: Yannis, I can't only agree with "flagged perfectly valid competing answers" in the part of "Valid" - they are invalid, because doesn't answer on asked question "local svn repo" - they offer hosting or DVCS. Answer of Mark also contain two errors and one mistake (or mispint), but I don't flag it (have to re-check) for Mercurial reference, because most part of answer was on-topic and relatively good. I read FAQ, and saw definition "not an answer" - most answers are not answers in the terms of FAQ. Sorry, it's true - and I have *nothing personal* against other answerers, only against content

Comment: @LazyBadger The flagging itself wouldn't have been a problem, if it was the only thing you did. I disagree on the validity of the answers, they stand perfectly as answers. I'm not saying they are good answers, or bad answers, but they are definitely not "not an answer". [This answer of yours](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/126745/25936) is an example of "not an answer", and coincidentally I've asked you to expand it more than three months ago, when I was a regular user.

Comment: Where in my initial comments in topic you found rudeness, show it, please: "-1 for answer on non-asked by OP question"?. Yes, I downvoted all wrong answers, and was honest to write why I done it. Nothing more. Mark copied my comment and downvoted me *after it* - and *I was offended* by the form and style. And **I'm offended by chauvinistic attitude** now - I see no equality, no justice. I wanted to provide for OP correct and best answers, and what I got? And what will get OP from a mix of answers about not his question?

Comment: @LazyBadger "-1 for answer on non-asked by OP question. Do not consider yourself smarter than others" is your first comment, and is rude, and quite pointless as you provide no actual information on why you think the answer is worth the downvote, other than the vague claim "for answer on non-asked by OP question". You yourself was offended when Mark posted it to your answer. Your "-1 for answer on non-asked by OP question" comments are similarly rude and pointless.

Comment: "they stand perfectly as answers" - sorry, if they doesn't answer on asked question (which was [mentioned by Mark](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142123/can-we-set-up-svn-server-on-a-local-computer-without-any-network-access#comment268275_142128)), how they can be answers? "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are... not even a *partial* answer to the actual question" DVCS or SVN-hosting isn't even partial answer on "Local SVN-repo". **It is true**, regardless of me and my opinions

Comment: @LazyBadger I disagree and I won't remove them. If you can convince a fellow moderator that they should be removed, so be it.

Comment: "You accused another user of stealing you answer" - I saw my error, I acknowledged that this is a mistake and I apologized. I am honest

Comment: @LazyBadger And I acknowledged the fact that you apologized, however that doesn't make up for the overall aggressiveness you displayed.

Comment: " If you can convince a fellow moderator that they should be removed" how I can *escalate problem of rejects*? I consider your decision, which **directly contradicts the written rules** as a result of a your biasing to me, and not as the exact execution of the local laws

Comment: @LazyBadger Feel free to contact Stack Exchange directly if you feel I'm biased against you.

Comment: "Feel free to contact Stack Exchange directly" - **I ASKED ALREADY - HOW TO DO THIS?!**

Comment: Email team@stackoverflow.com - it's at the foot of every page.